# Что означает слово SNAPSHOT в версии библиотеки?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

Очень часто при подключении библиотек можно встретить после номера версии слово SNAPSHOT.

Пример:

```
compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

Что оно означает?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SNAPSHOT` означает, что исходники будут дорабатываться в пределах данной версии. Условно говоря, если твоё приложение использует некую библиотеку, помеченную как `SNAPSHOT`, то её автор, найдя баг или просто внеся дополнительный функционал, а может и удалив что-то, может залить новый jar'ник библиотеки (артефакта), при этом не поменяв версию. Совесть автора будет чиста, а вот твоё приложение, заново потянув библиотеку из репозитория может уже не собраться.

Answer (score 5):

SNAPSHOT это зафиксированное состояние в системе управления версиями. Делаются ежедневно(или еженедельно, как разработка двигается). SNAPSHOT-версии могут оказаться вовсе не рабочими

Answer (score 5):

`SNAPSHOT` иногда означает, что это почти окончательный вариант данной версии. Что-то наподобие `release candidate`.

Если обычная версия это полностью законченный продукт, то версии `SNAPSHOT` могут получать обновления, т.к. предполагается, что продукт ещё находится в стадии разработки.

Более подробно можно почитать на английском SO [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it).

Comment: Не вводите людей в заблуждение фразой "это почти окончательный вариант данной версии. Что-то наподобие release candidate." Как уже [ответил Артём](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482096/182750) SNAPSHOT не что иное, как моментальный снимок. Приставка SNAPSHOT может быть и у самой первой версии, в которой ещё нет запланированного функционала.